# AngularJS JSON parse(ajax)

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I have been tring to make a ajax request but there seems to be a problem. When my json attributes names are in " ( like {"name":value"} ), it works but when attribute names are not. I have following excepiton

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
at Object.parse (native)
at pb (http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:12:472)
at Vc.d.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:92:314)
at http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:92:127
at Array.forEach (native)
at n (http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:6:192)
at Qb (http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:92:109)
at c (http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:93:295)
at h (http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:77:437)
at http://localhost:8080/angularjs/lib/angular.min.js:78:169
```

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/indexApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="AjaxController">
            {{users.data}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

indexApp.js

```
function AjaxController($scope, $http) {
$scope.beers = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
console.log("OMW");
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'data.json'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.users = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.users = "error" + data;
});
```

};

data.json

```
{
    success : "true",
    data: [{name:"val"}]
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You *must* wrap attribute names in `"`. This is the only way to specify valid transport JSON, which is stricter than object notation in an executable JavaScript context. Any JSON parser will fail if you try to use the more lax notation.

See also [the spec for JSON](http://json.org/) which mandates this.

Comment: @Ezekiel Victor  How did you wrapped the attributes name ??

Comment: @Despertaweb what do you mean? Wrap attribute name with double quotes; e.g. `"name"` instead of `name`. If you use any JSON serializer out there, e.g. `JSON.stringify(...)` or PHP `json_encode(...)` it will do that correctly for you.

Answer (score 8):

Even I had the similar issue and the solution is, your string data should be in a specific format for **JSON.parse** or **angular.fromJson** to work.

For ex:

```
var myString = '{"name":"nomad"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(myString));
```

---

The console output is: Object {name: "nomad"}

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.  One of the firstName was an empty string like this.
     `{"firstName":"", 
      "lastName":"Doe"}`
edit: This error can also mean there are some syntax errors in your json file mainly. for example commenting out some things within the json file or not giving space between commas separating two key value pairs also threw the same error. Very beginner mistake thought this would help others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was returning the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
>
> at Object.parse (native)
>
> at fromJson
>   (http://www.example.com/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1072:14)

So we found out that what was happening internally on angular was the following:

```
JSON.parse("{'error': 'message'}"); // error
```

And indeed it returns a parser error, since it's expected the JSON to have strings wrapped with `"`, [as the accepted answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16355633/1064325).

So, we just fixed the server response to comply with the [JSON string specification](http://www.json.org/):

```
JSON.parse('{"error": "message"}'); // works!
```